# Share folder from ubuntu one files android

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

Is it possible to directly share a folder from ubuntu one files for android? 
What about the app's developement? Does it stopped?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share a folder directly from Ubuntu One Files app (make it public nor make it a shared foler with other users). The REST API doesn't support these operations.